# Creating a second loop in a loop Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My script works fine for the first `i` loop but I needed to move it over to different column sections so added a `j` loop.
When I run this script I get stuck in a never ending loop and it takes me a while to get it stopped (or perhaps it reaches its 5 mins timeout).
I thought it would finish the `i`'s then add one to `j` loop through `i` etc.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var studentSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('student');
var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet6');

for ( var j = 1; j<10; i++) {
  for( var i = 2; i< 20; i++) {
    // copyTo rows

    sourceSheet.getRange(i, 6*j-3).copyTo(studentSheet.getRange(1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
    sourceSheet.getRange(i, 6*j-2).copyTo(studentSheet.getRange(2, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
    sourceSheet.getRange(i, 6*j-1).copyTo(studentSheet.getRange(3, 1), {contentsOnly: true});

    SpreadsheetApp.flush(); 

    // get value from calculated formula cell
    studentSheet.getRange(2, 22).copyTo(sourceSheet.getRange(i, 6*j), {contentsOnly: true})
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you calculated how long one loop takes? Your script has a LOT of usage of the Spreadsheet Service, which generally takes at least 0.2 sec per call. 9 values of `j`, each with 18 values of `i`, means your loop (which has 8 `getRanges` and 4 copies) executes 162 times... Consider implementing Apps Script "best practices".

Comment: Check you first loop for ( var j = 1; j<10; i++).  "i++"?

Comment: when I run with only the first loop it takes around 3-4 secs. When I have both together I can see the script working but it doesn't paste any final results just keep throwing values into the student sheet.

Comment: Thank you that rather obvious error has fixed it all